# glossaries-extra package help

Tags: glossaries-extra

I want to build a list of symbols using the glossaries-extra package but I am getting error saying "Error: Could not start the command: "makeglossaries.exe although I have specified the correct path for makeglossaries.exe file in miktex.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[automake,symbols]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{symbols}
\begin{document}

%\include{symbols}
%\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\printglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]

\chapter{sample symbols}
\include{sym_rough}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\glsxtrnewsymbol[description={Lower case, boldface and italic letter represents a vector}]{a}{\ensuremath{a}}
```

I have installed ActivePerl already and it is added to %PATH%. I have also entered the complete path to makeglossaries.exe in the MikTex installation.

Comment: Since you've used the `automake` package option, you shouldn't need to run `makeglossaries`.

Comment: I am getting error that **This document is incomplete. The external file associated with the glossary 'symbol' which should be called "thesis".sls) hasn't been created.**

Comment: for some odd reasons, when I reset the TeXstudio to its default settings and re-enter the complete paths for latex.exe etc, it solved the problem.

Comment: I think the problem was with **default compiler** as when I checked previously it had some additinal value other than pdflatex. Changing it back to its default value i.e. **pdflatex** solved the problem, I guess.
May be useful for someone else.

Comment: Since you're using TeXstudio, perhaps [this information](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries/index.shtml#texstudio) may help.